# Merge and make dictionary from Dataframe Columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame like this

```
Question        Response
"How are you?"  ["high","moderate"]
"how is it?"    ["cool","low"]
```

and i want the output df to be like

```
Question        Response                     
"How are you?"  [{"weight":"1","Response":"high"},{"Weight":"2","Response":"moderate"}]  
"how is it?"    [{"weight":"1","Response":"cool"},{"Weight":"2","Response":"low"}]
```

Comment: What is the "weight" key of the dictionary?

Comment: Explain a bit of your logic.

Comment: Weights are just count or index position+1 for example if response is ['a','b']
then the output must be
[{'weight":'1','response:"a"},{"weight":"2","response":"b"}]

Comment: @LiamFiddler please check the comment

Comment: @Erfan please check comment for logic.

Answer (score 0):

use `map` (
normally very fast):

```
df['Response'] = list(map(lambda val: list(map(lambda d:{'Weight' : d[0], 
                                                         'Response' : d[1]},
                                               enumerate(val, 1))),
                          df['Response']))
```

or `comprehension list`

```
df['Response'] = [[{'Weight' : weight, 'Response' : response} 
                   for weight, response in enumerate(val, 1)] 
                  for val in df['Response']]
```

**Output**

```
print(df)

         Question  \
0  "How are you?"   
1    "how is it?"   

                                                                   Response  
0  [{'Weight': 1, 'Response': 'high'}, {'Weight': 2, 'Response': 'moderate'}]  
1       [{'Weight': 1, 'Response': 'cool'}, {'Weight': 2, 'Response': 'low'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can write a custom function to create your dictionary's:

```
def convert_list(x):
    lst = [{'weight': i+1, 'Reponse': val} for i, val in enumerate(x)]
    return lst

df['Reponse'] = df['Response'].apply(lambda x: convert_list(x))

         Question  \
0  "How are you?"   
1    "how is it?"   

                                                                   Response  
0  [{'weight': 1, 'Reponse': 'high'}, {'weight': 2, 'Reponse': 'moderate'}]  
1       [{'weight': 1, 'Reponse': 'cool'}, {'weight': 2, 'Reponse': 'low'}]
```